# Trouble creating an iTunes style source list in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, user-interface

I'm working on a piece of software that would work well with an iTunes style source list. I have been looking around the net for how to implement it but all the examples seem a bit sketchy.

I found Mark Alldritt's [implementation](http://www.latenightsw.com/blog/?p=29) and tried to use it in my project but it is rendering incorrectly. The cells seem to be rendering half outside of the source list control.

Does anyone have experience with creating this sort of UI? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out:

http://code.google.com/p/sourcelist/

http://th30z.netsons.org/2009/03/cocoa-sidebar-with-badges-take-2/

http://www.mere-mortal-software.com/blog/details.php?d=2006-12-21